# Why is angular 6 loadChildren not working?

Tags: angular, angular6, lazy-loading, angular6-json-schema-form

I am new to angular, so I am learning through Udemy's video course "Angular6 The Complete Guide" by Maximilian Schwarzmüller. I am almost about to complete the course but stuck with lazyloading in the chapter "Adding Lazy Loading to the Recipes Module" under unit "Understanding Angular Modules and optimizing Apps". In this,the instructor separates out the entire recipes modules and its routing module. I tried doing the same for shopping module which has routing module at app root level -app-routing.module.ts

1) app-routing.module.ts code

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
  import { ShoppingListComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.component';
  import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

  const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'recipes', loadChildren: './recipes/recipes.module#RecipesModule'},
    { path: 'shopping-list', loadChildren: './shopping-list/shopping-list.module#ShoppingListModule'}
  //  { path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent }
  ];
  @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
  })
  export class AppRoutingModule {

  }
```

2)app.module.ts code

```
      import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

  // added below two
  import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
  // added header component
  // import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
  import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
  import { ShoppingListService } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.service';
  import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
  import { RecipeService } from './recipes/recipe.service';
  import { DataStorageService } from './shared/data-storage.service';
  import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
  import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth-guard.service';
  import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
  // import { ShoppingListModule } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.module';
  import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
  import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';


  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      // add header comp
      HeaderComponent,
      HomeComponent
        ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      // add Forms and HTTP module
      // FormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      SharedModule,
      // ShoppingListModule,
      AuthModule
    ],
    providers: [ShoppingListService, RecipeService, DataStorageService, AuthService, AuthGuard],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

So, why does this line of code don't work, even though there are no errors at all?

```
{ path: 'shopping-list', loadChildren: './shopping-list/shopping-list.module#ShoppingListModule'}
```

I attached my project file structure image[image: PROJECT FILE STRUCTURE]

Comment: Where is your shopping list routing module?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: nope, as per the instructor for this project shopping list routing module is not required and its already given in top level app-routing module.ts(pls check code above).  
   { path: 'shopping-list', loadChildren: './shopping-list/shopping-list.module#ShoppingListModule'}

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have shopping-list routing module

Comment: nope, as per the instructor for this project shopping list routing module is not required and its already given in top level app-routing module.ts(pls check code above).  
   { path: 'shopping-list', loadChildren: './shopping-list/shopping-list.module#ShoppingListModule'}

Comment: @devvab but this is how lazy loading work, in top app routing module you are saying lazy load shopping list routing, which does not exists. Look same you do with recipes, and there you do have routing module.

Comment: Please correct me if I got you right.

Let me first explain how lazy loading is done in recipe. I have a 

1)recipes.module.ts where I have a recipe NgModule which as all the recipe related components grouped together.

 RecipesComponent,
    RecipeStartComponent,
    RecipeListComponent,
    RecipeEditComponent,
    RecipeDetailComponent,
    RecipeItemComponent

2)recipes-routing.module.ts In this routing module, I have all the route paths for recipe components.

Comment: 3)In the top level app.module.ts, i lazy load the recipe module's route path as below intead of direcly loading the component.


        { path: 'recipes', loadChildren: './recipes/recipes.module#RecipesModule'}

Comment: So, as per your explaination I have to do a similar structure for shopping list by creating a shpping even if i have only two components:ShoppingListComponent, ShoppingEditComponent. So, I have to add shoppinglist-routing.module.ts  (which has  paths for shopping components ) for lazy loaing to work?So, i have to create shoppinglist-routing.module.ts  just for lazy loading to work and lazy loading for this shopping cannot be handled at app-routing.mudule.ts?

Comment: @devvab yes. Because you need to say router that when url  is "blabla" use component BlaBlaComponent